# MySQL query, select from table, and return values not found

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT phone
  FROM contacts
  WHERE (phone='123456' OR phone='456789' OR phone='789789')
     AND deleted=0 AND user=1
```

This will show me all rows that are in the contacts table, and they are not deleted. How can I return the values that are not found in the contacts table?

**Note:** *There is no found field in my table. That's what i want to return*
For example:

```
|   Phone   | deleted | found |
|-----------|---------|-------|
|  123456   |    0    |  YES  |
|  456789   |    1    |  YES  |
|  789789   |    0    |   NO  | <---
```

Thanks,
Nicos

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT(phone) FROM contacts WHERE (phone = '123456' OR phone = '456789' OR phone = '789789') AND deleted = 0 AND found = 'NO' AND user = 1`. You should use the "found" column too I guess.

Comment: there is no "found" column in my table, it was just to show, that the query was in the contacts Table, or not. '123456' AND '456789' are in my contacts table, '789789' is not, but i still want it returned in the query result

Comment: You want to get from the table some data that doesn't exist?

Comment: I want to get from the table, data that deleted=0, and data that are not included in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution: check result on PHP and verify not exist phones.

**EDIT:**

If you want run it as one query you can create this statement:

```
SELECT t.phone
FROM
(
  SELECT 123456 as phone
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 456789 as phone
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 789789 as phone
) as t
LEFT JOIN  contacts as c
  ON t.phone = c.phone
WHERE c.phone IS NULL
```

But I'm not certain that it will work fast

Comment: Stepozer, i thought i could find another solution, DB based, so i can save some PHP coding. So far, it is the only solution

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it easier to do this in PHP?

```
// The list of phone numbers to search
$listAll = array('123456', '456789', '789789', );

// Use data from $listAll to compose this query:
$query = "
  SELECT DISTINCT phone
  FROM contacts
  WHERE phone IN ('123456', '456789', '789789')
     AND deleted=0 AND user=1
";

// Run the query, get the list of phone numbers in $listFound
// Let's suppose it produces:
//     $listFound = array('123456', '456789');

// Get the list of phone numbers that are missing from table
$listMissing = array_diff($listAll, $listFound);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    select DISTINCT phone 
    from contacts 
    WHERE (phone='123456' OR phone='456789' OR phone='789789') 
    AND deleted = 0 
    AND user = 1
    AND found = 0
```

Comment: please read @Nicos answer `there is no "found" column in my table, `

Comment: So I don't know why he cannot achieve it.

Comment: Because `found` is not column. Row 789789 NOT exist in table. Query must return NOT existed phones in table.

Comment: See my answer to understand what it must to do

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT distinct phone 
FROM contacts 
WHERE phone NOT IN (123456,456789) AND
deleted = 0 AND 
user=1
```

Comment: please read @Nicos answer: `there is no "found" column in my table,`. So your answer is not correct. Row 789789 NOT exist in table. Query must return NOT existed phones in table.

Comment: No:) For example your table contain phones (123456, 456789). And when you run SELECT with phones  (123456, 456789, 789789) it must return phone 789789. Your query doesn't help with this:)

Comment: See my answer to understand what it must to do